# Updating a cocoa interface while processing code in a separate thread, using performSelectorInBackground

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, selector

I am writing an app that can revert the firmware of a particular device. While executing this revert code, I wish to display a progress indicator.

This problem is of course best tackled with the use of multiple threads (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225700/can-i-start-a-thread-by-pressing-a-button-in-a-cocoa-interface-and-keep-using-in).

I have implemented the performSelectorInBackground method, which (according to the documentation) launches the specified selector in a separate thread. Meanwhile, my GUI is updated from the main thread by querying the 'reverter' object.

However, the GUI does not seem to be updating until the code in the secondary thread has finished executing. I obviously need the two to run in parallel. Here is what I've got so far - I'd be really grateful for any help as this is my first time with threading.

```
-(IBAction)pushButton:(id)sender{
 //instatiate reverter object, which does all the firmware processing
 Reverter *reverter = [[Reverter alloc] init];  

//update the GUI to show a tab with a progress indicator    
[tabView selectTabViewItemWithIdentifier:@"RevertProgressTab"];

//process revert code in a separate thread  
[reverter performSelectorInBackground:@selector(revertFirmware) withObject:nil];

//process is complete when reverter progress reaches 100
while (!([reverter progress] == 100)) {

    //check for failure
    if ([reverter hasFailed]) {
        [self showRevertFailureTab:nil];
        return;
    }
    //update the progress indicator in the interface
    [revertProgressBar setDoubleValue:(double)[reverter progress]];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.05];
}

[self showRevertSuccessTab:nil];    


}
```

Have I done anything obvious that would stop the GUI from being updated while the revertFirmware method runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop

```
while (/*condition*/) {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:x];
}
```

will prevent your UI from updating. Your UI will only update as soon as your *pushButton:* method returns.

Instead of polling I would advice you start using an asynchronous event model:

**Add a delegate to your reverter object**

```
@protocol ReverterDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) reverterProgressDidUpdate:(float)progress;
@end

@interface Reverter : NSObject {
    id<ReverterDelegate> delegate;
}
@property(assign) id<ReverterDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

**Register your controller class as a delegate to your reverter**

```
reverter.delegate = self;
```

and handle that event

```
- (void) reverterProgressDidUpdate:(float)progress {
    // update ui
}
```

**In your background thread send out events to the main thread**

```
- (void) revertFirmware {
    // once in a while send notifications of progress updates
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(reverterProgressDidUpdate:)]) {
        [self.delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reverterProgressDidUpdate:) withObject:[NSNumber numerWithFloat:progress] waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}
```

Make sure you retain your reverter somewhere, and release it when it's done working. You are now leaking in your *pushButton:* method. Also this is just a suggestion towards a better model. Instead of using performSelectorInBackground you could take a look at NSOperation and NSOperationQueue for example.

Comment: Thanks very much, I will try that! This button will only be pressed once per application run (reverting the firmware is the application's sole function), so memory leak shouldn't be a problem (right?). The reverter is currently defined as an instance variable (I made it local to the method in the above code, for simplicity), and I release it on dealloc of the controller class.

Comment: Oh, and just incase anyone reads this in future, the controller class must also implement the delegate:

@interface Controller : NSObject <ReverterDelegate> {
}

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I changed the following two lines to remove some warnings:

NSObject<ReverterDelegate> *delegate; 


@property(assign) NSObject<ReverterDelegate> *delegate;